# Can fiances take on each other's customs before marriage?

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage, engagement-shidduch

Can two people who are engaged take on each other's customs before marriage? At what point in the marriage process do they take on each other's customs?

Comment: Isn't a person supposed to adhere to his parents' minhag before marriage?